# How can I set d3 linearScale tick start and each stop length

Tags: d3.js, charts

I want to change linearScale tick start and stop length. Say one linearScale domain (0-100) but tick is start in 20 and each tick stop 10. When use `scale.ticks()` generate tick list like: [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you add code showing how you're adding the tick marks? That'll make it easier for us to help out.

Answer (score -1):

It's a little difficult to generate the appropriate approach without seeing your code, but I've written something up for you using some generic names, assuming you've used an x scale called `xScale`.

There are many ways to do this, but the simplest is to generate the 10 ticks, but only show the ones with the relevant values.

```js
const ticksNum = 10

const yourAxis = svg.
     .append('g')
     .attr('class', 'axis x')
     .call(
     d3.axisBottom(xScale)
     .tickFormat(d3.format(''))
     .ticks(ticksNum)
     )

d3.select('.x.axis')
  .selectAll('g.tick')
     .select('text')
     .style('visibility', d => {
       if(d===10){return 'hidden'}
       return 'visible')
     })
     .text(d => d)
```

If you'd like to exclude multiple ticks, just edit the line that says `if(d===10)` to include tick values other than 10.

Otherwise, you can make sure that the very first tick (or any tick of offset `i`) is invisible using the following:

```js
const ticksNum = 10

const yourAxis = svg.
     .append('g')
     .attr('class', 'axis x')
     .call(
     d3.axisBottom(xScale)
     .tickFormat(d3.format(''))
     .ticks(ticksNum)
     )

d3.select('.x.axis')
  .selectAll('g.tick')
     .select('text')
     .style('visibility', (d,i) => {
       if(i===0){return 'hidden'}
       return 'visible')
     })
     .text(d => d)
```